# Как вычислить vh, имея px?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть определённое значение, заданное в **px** и нужно получить значение в **vh**
В интернете ничего похожего я не нашёл.

Comment: `valVh = ~~ ( valPx / document.body.clientHeight * 100 );`